# Using images as emojis in a contenteditable div used as a chat input

Tags: javascript, range, chat, selection, emoji

I have a little chat feature I am working on and I am using images as emojis.

What I did was, when an emoji is clicked two elements are created, the first is a span with the background image of the emoji, the second is another span with the actual emoji as its content, the first span is the parent of the second, so I set the visibility of the second span to 'hidden' with CSS so the background image of the first span is visible from behind.

But the issue is when I click on an emoji to send it(the combination of the two span elements described above) to the message input(a contenteditable div in this case) the caret is placed before the image emoji(the span elements combination) instead of behind it. For example if the content of the input before I click on an emoji is 'hello' after I click on an emoji it becomes 'hello(cursor)(emoji)' instead of 'hello(emoji)(cursor)', if I add another emoji it becomes 'hello(cursor)(emoji)(emoji)' instead of 'hello(emoji)(emoji)(cursor)', please how do I fix this?

Here are my codes below:

```js
const chatInput = document.querySelector("div#chat-input");
const grinningFace = document.querySelector("span#grinning-face");
const rocket = document.querySelector("span#rocket");

chatInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.key === "Enter"){
        event.preventDefault();
        const message = document.createElement("div");
        message.textContent = chatInput.innerText;
        chatInput.innerHTML = "";
    }
})


grinningFace.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

grinningFace.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const content = grinningFace.querySelector("span")

    const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const emojiImage = document.createElement("span");
    const emojiImageContent = document.createElement("span");
    emojiImage.classList.add("emoji-image");
    emojiImage.style.backgroundImage = `${getComputedStyle(grinningFace).backgroundImage}`;
    emojiImage.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
    emojiImageContent.textContent = content.textContent;
    emojiImage.appendChild(emojiImageContent);

    range.insertNode(emojiImage);
    // Get the next text node and set the cursor at its start
    const nextTextNode = emojiImage.nextSibling;
    if (nextTextNode && nextTextNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        const newRange = document.createRange();
        newRange.setStart(nextTextNode, 0);
        newRange.collapse(true);
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(newRange);
        chatInput.focus();
    }

    
});

rocket.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    chatInput.focus();
});
```

```css
div#chat-msgs {
    height: 70%;
    border: 1px solid #686868a1;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

span#grinning-face {
    background-image: url(./emojis/grinning-face.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

span#grinning-face > span {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit; width: inherit;
}

span#rocket {
    background-image: url(./emojis/rocket.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}

span#rocket > span {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit; width: inherit;
}

div#chat-input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 41px;width: calc(100% - 8px);
    line-height: 41px;
    border: 1px solid #686868a1;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px
}

div#chat-input:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
}

.emoji-image {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    left: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    background-size: contain;
}

.emoji-image > span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
        <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat-msgs">
        </div>
        <div id="emojis">
            <span id="grinning-face"><span></span></span>
            <span id="rocket"><span></span></span></div>
        <div id="chat-input" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter a message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```